# PHP variable used in shell_exec giving different results

Tags: php, html, post, shell-exec

This is a repost because my question before was not clear enough and deleted it to prevent further confusion.

I have a shell script that takes one argument. It uses the argument to cURL a website which then uses grep, head and ${variable#*>} to extract some data from a website.

In terminal everything works well with the command below. $stockCode being the argument. ./priceAlert.sh $stockCode

I tried to make this into a working webpage on my local host. (MAMP osx) I tried different solutions but the website will always spit out "not from same origin" except for the shell script.

After searching for how to integrate shell scripts with web I came across PHP and now I am figuring out how to get PHP to talk to my shell script.

Structure of my project:

1. HTML page with an input inside a form

   ```
   <form action="priceAlert.php" method="post">
       <input type="text" name="stockCode"></input>
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit me!">
   </form>
   ```
2. A PHP page that receives the input from the HTML page via POST

   ```
   $stockCode2 = $_POST['stockCode'];
   echo $stockCode2;
   $output = shell_exec('sh priceAlert2.sh ' . $stockCode2);
   echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
   ```

Now the interesting part...
The value of $stockCode2 from the HTML form is 033360.

If I use $stockCode2 as POST, the shell script extracts the part of the website that I do not want. (The code above extracts the part I do not want)

If I hard code the value, 033360, into $stockCode2 the shell script extracts the part I want. The code below extracts the part of the website I do want.

```
    $stockCode2 = '033360';
    $output = shell_exec('sh priceAlert2.sh ' . $stockCode2);
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

If I echo everything they all show the value 033360 but behave differently.

Is there a way to fix this? Could this be a way for the target site to prevent scraping?

Thank you.

Comment: You should use [`escapeshellarg`](http://php.net/escapeshellarg) on the passed shell argument to prevent command injection.

Comment: you use like this? $output = shell_exec('sh priceAlert2.sh ' . escapeshellarg($stockCode2)); Unfortunately that didn't work :(

Comment: This was a general recommendation and not specific to your problem.